# JUnit Testing in Netbeans 8.1

Tags: java, netbeans, junit

I have been working on a Java Application [That uses Servlets, etc]. And I was hoping to run JUnit Testing for my Controller methods. However, after adding the libraries of JUnit 4.12 and Hamcrest 1.3 & generating the test cases using NetBeans on my controllers. I have faced this problem when I ran the test.

**Testsuite: controller.AccountControllerTest
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0 sec**

Testcase: controller.AccountControllerTest:BeforeFirstTest: Caused an ERROR
null
junit.framework.AssertionFailedError
    at org.netbeans.core.execution.RunClassThread.run(RunClassThread.java:153)

Test controller.AccountControllerTest FAILED (crashed)

I have not been able to find anything online that is related to this issue. Could anybody help me out here? Thank you!

*EDIT*: Apologies as this is my first time asking a question. Thanks for taking a look!

CODE:

```
public class AccountControllerTest {

@BeforeClass
public static void setUpClass() {
}

@AfterClass
public static void tearDownClass() {
}

@Before
public void setUp() {
}

@After
public void tearDown() {
}

/**
 * Test of register method, of class AccountController.
 */
@Test
public void testRegister() {
    System.out.println("register");
    String username = "";
    String password = "";
    String cfmPassword = "";
    String email = "";
    String name = "";
    ArrayList<String> errorList = null;
    AccountController instance = new AccountController();
    instance.register(username, password, cfmPassword, email, name, errorList);
    // TODO review the generated test code and remove the default call to fail.
    fail("The test case is a prototype.");
}
}
```

Error Stacktrace:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError:
>   junit.framework.TestResult.addListener(Ljunit/framework/TestListener;)V
>   at junit.framework.TestResult.addListener(Native Method) at
>   org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.junit.IgnoredTestResult.addListener(IgnoredTestResult.java:49)
>   at
>   org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.junit.JUnitTestRunner.run(JUnitTestRunner.java:357)
>   at
>   org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.junit.JUnitTestRunner.launch(JUnitTestRunner.java:1179)
>   at
>   org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.junit.JUnitTestRunner.main(JUnitTestRunner.java:1030)

Comment: please share the code and the complete stacktrace.

Comment: Could you share also how you set up your project? Especially where the `org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.junit.JUnitTestRunner` is comming from. This class is not part of the JUnit version you mention. Most probably you are mixing some stuff.

Comment: I simply created a JSP project, added the test methods via NetBeans (by right-clicking and generating tests for the controller). I did nothing regarding the org.apache side. This error comes upon running the test file.